# NN model predicting same thing everytime

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, mnist

I am making an Digit Classifying model with pytorch using the MNIST data set and when i train and evaluate my model I am getting 97-99% accuracy but then when I save and load the model and pass something through the model the predicted output is the same thing every time. In this case it is 5.

I tried to google it chat gpt it restart and nothing is working. I thought if I started fresh I would be able to fix the problem but unfortunately I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Without showing your code, we cannot help you find the error.

Comment: Check your weights after the loading - and compare them to your weights after training, they have probably been reset.